# android - Service need internet connection

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-networking, android-syncadapter

So, I have a service that is supposed to send data to my server via MQTT. This process of sending of data is supposed to happen every 10 minutes and must be done regardless of the state of my application (Paused/Stopped/Destroyed). So, the conclusion here is my service needs internet connection even when the phone is in idle state in order to function properly.

The approach that I have taken is: Using `AlarmManager` and a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` to run `Service` described in the first paragraph.

The steps can be described as follows:

1. Attempt to connect to MQTT broker
2. Upon successful connection, do some logic and publish message to server
3. Upon successful message publish, disconnect from broker and clean up resources

The above sub-routine is supposed to be executed every 10 minutes.

The problem now is, after 3-4 minutes of idle state, my service is unable to connect to the MQTT broker because there seems to be no internet connection. 
I checked the internet connection via:

```java
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
      = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
Log.wtf(TAG, "internet: " + (activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected());
```

How do I acquire internet access for my service? The only thing that I haven't tried is using [evernote/android-job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job). But before that, I would like to gain some information because I suspect the only way that I can solve this is by somehow acquiring internet access every time my service run.

I have browsed quite a bit on this topic, but all I came across is answers pertaining to ***'How to check internet connection in background service'*** which is not what I need. What I need is '***how to acquire internet connection when phone is idle for every time my service runs?***'

Please ask me if you need code snippets, or other information that I failed to include above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: want to access wifi or mobile data?

Comment: both works. As long as there is internet connection.

Comment: so, internet connection becomes unavailable to my service after 3-4 minutes is a normal behavior?

Comment: No I didn't say that, but if the connection is unavailable and you want to access mobile data, then you have to ask user to turn it on. Or just turn on wifi programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Sync Adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html). It will sync your data in the background at opportune moments to prevent unnecessary battery drain and service charges.

Comment: Will try to use it.

Comment: Accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: Is there no way to know when the sync adapter runs?

Comment: If you send a broadcast when the adapter runs you can listen to that.

Comment: question, if I manually invoke the `onPerformSync`, it still ensures internet connection, right?

Answer (score 1):

**how to acquire internet connection when phone is idle for every time my service runs?**

You cannot access mobile data on / off programmatically above android 4.4 .It have been made stopped for security reasons ,instead you can ask the user using a dialog to enable the mobile data and then if he enable you can do your task.

So every time you start your service, ask user to enable mobile data.

**However You can connect to WiFi programmatically:**

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(status);
```

And set `status` to `true` or `false` as per your need.

Comment: I thought WifiLock is used for connecting to Wifi programmatically?

Comment: @andyaldoo Wifi manager is used for that. See the code above :)

Answer (score 1):

Android syncadapter mechanism give an efficient way to transfering data.You can read more at [sync adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) and
[Transfering data using sync adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html)

Comment: I'll let you know once I implemented this

Answer (score 0):

Test your application in below 23 API. Because above 23 your application may not access the internet data because of **

> "DOZE MODE"

**

So to overcome from that problem user must have to allow your app to run in background.

This is happening because of battery optimization. So please test it on below 23 and let me know if that works or not.

Comment: I'm using API 19

Comment: The internet connection seems to be unavailable to my service only. I was able to verify this by browsing instagram while my service runs on the background

Answer (score 0):

You can't force the phone to be online, you are at the whim of the user. The best you can do is check for internet connectivity, but if connectivity is off, there is no way for you to turn it on.

Your best approach would be to use the JobScheduler or Google GCM network manager, see these: [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html), [GCM Network Manager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager)

With these you can schedule your job to fire at periodic intervals, only when network is available. If you truly need 10 minute periods and network, you will have to inform the user to ensure network is ON at all times, but you will still have to account for network being off.

Comment: Will using JobScheduler or GCM Network Manager solves the internet connection issue? cause if those are just another way of running a service periodically, then the underlying problem is still there.

Comment: With JobScheduler and GCM you can specify that your task requires internet connectivity, so it will only fire when the requirements are satisfied.

Comment: That's not what I want though. The service requires internet connection. So, without internet connection, the service will fail. Using these two techniques will only allow my service to run only if there is internet connection. I can't have that, I need the service to always run every 10 minutes

Comment: You can't have it your way; you can't control when connectivity will be on or off. As I mentioned, your best approach is to have the system wake your service up when the conditions are right for your task to run.